# Segmentation fault error when using fgets in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, glibc

I use the `fgets()` function in assembly and it should work, but I have a problem with my buffer. Is there a way to define a char pointer?  I ask because the function needs a char pointer as the first argument.

Here you can see my code:

```
; nasm fgets.asm -f elf64 -o fgets.o
; gcc -no-pie fgets.o
; ./a.out

; Define fgets as an external function
extern fgets

SECTION .DATA
buffer: db "0000000000", 0

SECTION .TEXT
    global main

main:
    push rbp ; Push stack

    ; Set up parameters and call the C function

    mov rdi, buffer
    mov rsi,10
    mov rdx, 1
    mov rax,0
    call fgets

    pop rbp     ; Pop stack

    mov rax,0   ; Exit code 0
    ret         ; Return
```

I want to read something from the stdin which is a maximum of 10 characters long.

Comment: You've set up the buffer correctly -- your problem is the third argument (in rdx), which needs to be a `FILE *`, not a file descriptor.

Comment: Do you know how I can read from stdin?

Comment: Yes, load the value of `FILE *stdin` from the global variable `[stdin]`.  Look at compiler output (but beware GNU .intel_syntax vs. NASM syntax differences)

Comment: Note that `stdin` is not necessarily a global variable -- in non-glibc implementations it might be a macro accessing some array or other object with a different name.  But as long as you only care about glibc, you should be fine with `mov rdx, qword [stdin]`

Comment: You don't need to zero AL first; `fgets` doesn't take a variable number of args.  It doesn't *hurt*, but it's as irrelevant as `mov ecx, 0`.

Answer (score 5):

A `FILE *` is not a file descriptor. Instead of passing `1` like you do, pass `[stdin]` (this works because `stdin` is a global pointer in glibc, and the keyword `stdin` in NASM is a pointer to that):

```
    mov rdx, [stdin]
```

If you use GAS, this will work:

```
    mov stdin, %rdx
```

However, you should probably be using RIP-relative addressing; this allows your executable to be relocated and is required for PIE (position-independent executable)s, which are the default now. In NASM, simply put this at the top of the file:

```
default rel
```

In GAS, it's a bit more complicated. You have to add `(%rip)` to all the external symbols you use, like this:

```
    mov stdin(%rip), %rdx
```

This loads the memory located at `stdin` (which is the 8-byte `FILE *` pointer you're looking for) into `rdx`.

Comment: Thanks man it worked with [stdin] but I also have a segmentation error, when I write soemthing to console :(

Comment: @JanWolfram Sorry, think this should fix it.

Comment: Why would you remove the RIP-relative addressing and explanation?  In x86-64 GAS code, you always want `mov symbol(%rip), %reg`, not `mov symbol, %reg`.  Same in NASM: `default rel` or `[rel symbol]`.  Also, `stdin` isn't a *keyword*, just a symbol name.

Comment: @PeterCordes Because it wasn't *my* answer anymore. I'll write more in and add a note about that, if you'd like.

Comment: Ok, I can post what I wrote as my own answer if you don't want it in yours.  If you understand and agree with what I wrote, feel free to use it in yours, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will, don't worry. I'm just rephrasing it. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterCordes Is there anything I left out that you think was important?

Comment: I liked my explanation of why it's a load and not just putting the address of the symbol `stdin` into a register.  I also wouldn't lead with the bad GAS way of doing the load.  I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` takes a `FILE *` *pointer* arg, not an integer file descriptor, as the 3rd arg.

Also, `1` is the stdout file descriptor, not `stdin`.  But anyway, when `fgets` dereferences `1` as a pointer it segfaults.  You could have seen this using a debugger to find the instruction that faulted.

In C you'd call `fgets(buf, len, stdin)`.  The global variable `stdin` is a pointer of type `FILE *stdin`.  This pointer  value (to an opaque `FILE` struct) is itself stored in memory at the symbol address `stdin`.  (Glibc's startup code initializes this pointer to point at a `FILE` struct it allocates).

Therefore you want to *load* a qword pointer from static storage as the 3rd arg for `fgets`.  You could have seen this yourself by looking at compiler output for the C function.

```
default rel            ; Use RIP-relative addressing by default
extern  stdin
extern  fgets

...
main:
    push   rax             ; dummy push to realign the stack by 16
   ...
    lea    rdi, [buffer]       ; RIP-relative LEA, or mov edi, buffer in a non-PIE
    mov    esi, buffer.len
    mov    rdx, [stdin]
    call   fgets
   ...
    pop    rcx             ; dummy pop to readjust RSP
   ret

section .bss
 buffer: resb 11      ; reserve 11 bytes, zero-filled
 .len equ $ - buffer
```

Note that it's not just `lea rdx, [stdin]` or `mov edx, stdin` to put the *address* of the `stdin` variable itself in a register.  `fgets` takes the pointer arg by value, not as a pointer to a pointer, and it's not `FILE stdin`, it's `FILE *stdin`.

I got the assembler to calculate the length of `buffer` for me.  I filled it with zero bytes instead of ASCII `'0'` characters.

**`fgets()` reads at most len-1 bytes,** and writes a terminating `\0` after those, so you need to pass `11` (the size of the full buffer) to read up to 10 bytes.

`fgets` isn't variadic so you don't need to zero AL before calling it.